# How to do a mouse click event on tableview JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a tableview with a model class for it. The table view shows all groups that a user can join and I would like to have a mouseclick event on the row of a tableView that a user clicks. This will change a text on a label to say if there is space in the group or not.

The problem that i am getting is "Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: Error resolving onMouseClicked='#clickItem', either the event handler is not in the Namespace or there is an error in the script." I am using a scene builder and have declared the method to  "On Mouse Clicked" and still getting the error.

Would be helpful if you can tell me a solution to be able to do this or fix the error. Thanks in advance.

```
public void showAvailability(MouseEvent event) { 

    selected = groupsTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    boolean checkAvailability  = checkSpaceInGroup(selected);

    if(checkAvailability){
        availabilityStatus.setText("Space in Group");
        availabilityPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "388e3c ");
    }
    else{
        availabilityStatus.setText("NO SPACE");
        availabilityPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #" + "ffcdd2 ");

    }
}
```

Comment: I recommend listening to the selection model instead. `groupsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((o, oldSelection, newSelection) -> { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have imported wrong library: (not sure without looking at the whole code)

```
import java.awt.event.??
```

instead of:

```
import javafx.event.??
```

However you can create an event from your Initialize method, on controller class, like this:

```
groupsTable.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event) -> { 
 //your code goes here
}
```

In this case, MouseEvent is imported using:

```
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: You sir are a legend! You are correct i did import import java.awt.event.?? and i have created the event on the initialize method and it worked. Thanks!!!